# What is similar to ng-max for input field of type text in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a decimal number input field on a modal form in which I want make sure the user inputs a value less than another base value in my application like below.

```
<input name="modalInput" type="text" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber" required max="data.baseNumber" />
```

But somehow the ng-max does not seem to trigger this validation and set the input box invalid. What could I be missing?

I would like to keep the type to be text so the up and down arrows are not displayed. And user can enter **4 or 5 digit numbers with decimal places**. 
Maybe the question should be what else can I use instead of ng-max that the value is validated against the base number.

**Sample plunker**

> http://plnkr.co/edit/9SAgqkjOlqUEHXhcyaqB?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the input type to `number` instead of `text`.

Answer (score 0):

The max and min attributes works with the following input types: `number`, `range`, `date`, `datetime`, `datetime-local`, `month`, `time` and `week`.

```
<input name="mainInput" type="number" size="10" ng-model="data.baseNumber" ng-max="3" required/>
```

To see the style changes add CSS rule

```
.ng-invalid{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**Plunnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/9SAgqkjOlqUEHXhcyaqB?p=preview)

Comment: @slacker does it helped?

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
<input name="modalInput" type="number" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber" required max="data.baseNumber" />
```

If you want to keep type="text" I think you can not use ng-max to validate text type. So you can create an event for the input ng-change="change()"

```
<input name="modalInput" type="text" class="form-control" size="10" ng-model="data.myNumber" required ng-change="change()"  />
```

The change() function to check max value for you when user enter

```
$scope.change = function(value) {
    if (value> maxValue){// Do something here}
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program has one error also with that. 
TypeError: Cannot read property '$valid' of undefined

match the name of the form, you did mismach as **numberForm**, **modalForm**

Aslo make the field as **number** as **type**